# How to avoid having version numbers in .so file name

Tags: linux, qt, shared-libraries, qmake

I'm trying to build a dynamic library on Linux using qmake. Here is my .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = sqxUiBase
QT += core gui   
CONFIG += dll    
INCLUDEPATH += ../../public/include   
DEPENDPATH += .
UI_DIR += ../GeneratedFiles    
RCC_DIR += ../GeneratedFiles   
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = ../lib/release
    LIBS += -L"../lib/release"
    MOC_DIR += ../GeneratedFiles/release
    OBJECTS_DIR += release
} else {    
    DESTDIR = ../lib/debug
    LIBS += -L"../lib/debug"
    MOC_DIR += ../GeneratedFiles/debug
    OBJECTS_DIR += debug
} 

include(sqxUiBase.pri)
```

The sqxUiBase.pri file contains the list of files that need to be built.

Now, the problem is that whatever I do, the resulting file is always named `sqxUiBase.so.1.0.0`, with a bunch of symlinks (`sqxUiBase.so`, `sqxUiBase.so.1` and `sqxUiBase.so.1.0`) pointing to it. How can I make it so that there's only a `sqxUiBase.so` file and no links?

Comment: Please don't write tags in titles. Thanks, past Etienne!

Comment: Back in 2010 that wasn't a rule ;)

Comment: Meh, it was always silly, due to the existence of the tags system!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you are looking for is making a `plugin`.

Add `CONFIG += plugin` to your project file, and qmake will generate a Makefile that builds a `libFoo.so` file, without the numbered links

Comment: As an additional option, you can specify an empty version number in the .pro file with "VERSION=" (without quotes). I can only attest to it working under Windows.

Answer (score 14):

After looking at the qmake source I found `CONFIG += unversioned_libname` for nix and `CONFIG += skip_target_version_ext` for windows.

Comment: This is the patch which introduced `unversioned_libname` https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-external-qtbase/commit/a162a3cbbc3c27b42c86f870aba051a408f04ed4 .

It works starting from qt 5.3

Comment: You'll also want `CONFIG += unversioned_soname` so that when linking it doesn't look for `foo.so.1`.